# How to create object hierarchy with dapper.net?

Tags: dapper

I have a table defination as below:

```
enter code here

CREATE TABLE Milestone
( 
    MilestoneID Int,
    MilestoneName Nvarchar(256),
    ParentMilestoneID Int
)
```

Class defination as below:

```
enter code here

public class Milestone
{
    public int MilestoneID {get;set;}
    public string MilestoneName {get;set:}
    public Milestone milestone {get;set;}
}
```

How to mapping sql query to parent-child hierarchy objects?

Any suggestion or idea is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly a hierarchy, but is better a parent-child relationship, I suppose you can look in the [example page](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) in the section called [Multi Mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping).